# window.jQuery.ui is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi in my website i loaded all jquery javascripts and css but i write console.log(window.jQuery.ui); it returns undefined. I dont know why.

So if i write  $(".tooltip").tooltip();
It says:TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'

My code is shown below:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href="css/epoch_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery.selectbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/OnlineRezervasyon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery.ui.tooltip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/epoch_classes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Because $(".tooltip").tooltip() not working.

Comment: yep i see now. you can follow as @khior answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console will always return `undefined` because jQuery UI extends the jquery object itself, it doesn't get added as a property of the jQuery object. That is why you can do this:

```
$('a.button').button();
```

instead of:

```
$('a.button').ui.button();
```

Also, you will need to swap the following lines around like so to make sure you don't get any jQuery UI errors:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/epoch_classes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I did what you say. When i write console $(".tooltip").tooltip();
It says:TypeError: Cannot call method 'tooltip' of undefined

Comment: Your block of script tags should now look like my edited answer, is this the case?

Comment: Did not work for me. Getting same error:TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'

Comment: Can you replicate this in a jsfiddle?